# how to make every button have its respective text appear next to it, when hovered and still apply the type animation

Tags: javascript

```js
const navList = document.getElementById("navigation");
const hoveredHome = document.querySelector(".nav_home");
const hoveredAbout = document.querySelector(".nav_about");
const hoveredSkills = document.querySelector(".nav_skills");
const hoveredContact = document.querySelector(".nav_contact");

const texts = [' // Home'];
const text2 = [' // About']
let count = 0; // counts the individual characters in array numbers
let characters = 0; // counts the individual letters/characters
let currentWord = '';
let letter = ''; //specifies individual letter, one by one

function typing() {

  // currentWord needs to change depending on what button is hovered
    currentWord = texts[count];
    letter = currentWord.slice(0, ++characters); //adds one character at a time
    document.querySelector(".nav_home").textContent = letter; //adds letter
    setTimeout(typing, 50);   
};

document.querySelector(".hovered").addEventListener('mouseover', typing);
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
                <nav id="navigation">
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-home"></div></i><p class="nav_home"></p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></div></i><p class="nav_about"></p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-code"></i></div><p class="nav_skills"></p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></div></i><p class="nav_contact"></p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></div><p class="nav_blog"></p></a></div>         
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="./javaScript/navAnimate.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Edited question, im trying to make it so when the icons are hovered text appears next to them, and eventually when they are not hovered the text dissapears.

Comment: Can you please use the snippet function in SO and add your HTML as well. This code is incomplete and it's unclear to me what it does via the button hovers. Add the infos by editing your question.

Comment: You are replacing text in `.nav_home`, use `+=` not `=`. `document.querySelector(".nav_home").textContent += letter; //adds letter`

Comment: You could use some css like `.hovered:hover .nav_home{display:block}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript at all. You can do this with pure CSS - in only one line *(once you do the initial styling)*. This is the one line that does the work:

```
a:hover .nav_text{display:block;}
```

```css
a{display:flex;min-height:50px;}

.nav_text{display:none;}

.hovered{display:flex;align-items:center;padding-right:5px;}

#navigation a:hover .nav_text{display:block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
                <nav id="navigation">
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div><p class="nav_text">Home</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></div><p class="nav_text">Aboot, eh?</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-code"></i></div><p class="nav_text">Skills</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></div><p class="nav_text">Contact</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></div><p class="nav_text">Blog</p></a></div>         
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

However, if you wanted to do it with javascript, here's the code that would make this work for you:

```js
//Look closely - this is NOT jQuery
//const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document); //<== not needed in _this_ example

const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const links = $$('#navigation .hovered');
$$('#navigation a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', evt => {
    const atag = evt.target.closest('a');
    const ntxt = atag.getElementsByClassName('nav_text');
    ntxt[0].style.display = 'block';
  });
  link.addEventListener('mouseout', evt => {
    const atag = evt.target.closest('a');
    const ntxt = atag.getElementsByClassName('nav_text');
    ntxt[0].style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#navigation a{display:flex;min-height:50px;}

.nav_text{display:none;}

.hovered{display:flex;align-items:center;padding-right:5px;}

.nav_show{display:block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
                <nav id="navigation">
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div><p class="nav_text nav_home">Home</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></div><p class="nav_text nav_about">Aboot, eh?</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-code"></i></div><p class="nav_text nav_skills">Skills</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></div><p class="nav_text nav_contact">Contact</p></a></div>
                  <div class="length_size"><a href="#"><div class="hovered"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></div><p class="nav_text nav_blog">Blog</p></a></div>         
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

*You might already know this, but please note that I prefixed several element tagNames/classNames with `#navigation` just to ensure that the correct `a` tags or `.hovered` elements were selected (in case you had others elsewhere on your page - quite likely with the a tag). If you added class names to the `a` tags (and used the className instead of `a`, and ensured that the `.hovered` className was truly unique, you would not need the `#navigation` selector.*

Comment: I have asked this question terribly, i apologize! I edited the question too. so I wanted the text to appear as if its being typed, and i was struggling to figure out how to write the javascript code in a clean way without having to repeat for each hovered link if that makes sense? thanks for your answer though!